# How do I check the TARGET_NAME of my iPhone app on XCode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, preprocessor

I'm trying to have 2 version of my iPhone application within the same XCode project.
The codebase it's almost the same and where I need to have different behaviours I've decided to use preprocessor's conditionals and the `${TARGET_NAME}` tag.

I've set the `OTHER_CFLAGS` to contain "`-DTARGET_NAME=${TARGET_NAME}`".

Then in my code I tried to do

```
#if TARGET_NAME == myApp
  NSLog(@"pro");
#elif TARGET_NAME == myAppLite
  NSLog(@"lite");
#endif
```

Unfortunately I always get "lite" printed out since `TARGET_NAME == myApp` it's always true: since `TARGET_NAME` is defined. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to evaluate this string comparison.
Any idea?

thanks in advance

Comment: don't you mean you always get "pro" printed out since `TARGET_NAME == myApp` is always true?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't compare strings like that in an `#if` block. Instead, add the defines to each specific target. For instance, on the full version's target, open the Info panel and go to the build tab and add something like `FULL_VERSION` to the `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` build setting. Then, for the lite target, enter something like `LITE_VERSION`. In your code, you can do:

```
#ifdef FULL_VERSION
NSLog(@"Full");
#else
NSLog(@"Lite");
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll do in this way. At the beginning I was going for this solution anyway, but I got stuck with the #if block comparison since I've found those on some blogs (like "here":http://www.pacificspirit.com/blog/2009/01/27/building_for_multiple_iphone_targets_in_xcode ) but it seems it's impossible... thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can get the target's name to compare it, but this will not skip unnecessary code from other targets at compile time, to do this:

First go to menu Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme... (or CMD + <)
Then in the arguments section, add inside environment variables something like:

[image: setup environment variables]

In your code you can get the target's name as:

```
NSString *targetName = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment][@"TARGET_NAME"];
NSLog(@"target = %@", targetName); // Will print the target's name
```

You can compare that string now in runtime.

But following your example: if you want that all the Pro version code to be omitted at compile time. You should do what @jason-coco says. And go to **preprocessor macros** in build settings, and add *`$(TARGET_NAME)`* there:

[image]

The code inside the #define will be compiled and executed if my target is "MLBGoldPA"

```
#if defined MLBGoldPA
    NSLog(@"Compiling MLBGoldPA");
#endif
```

Answer (score -1):

to get your conditional evaluation working, you have to do something like:

```
#define myApp       1
#define myAppLite   2
```

beforehand, like in your _Prefix.pch file.