# xcode4:build depending on target

Tags: xcode4, preprocessor

I have two targets for my project: one is the App, and the other is UT.I'd like to return different results for one method depending on the target. 

I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027091/how-do-i-check-the-target-name-of-my-iphone-app-on-xcode) but failed.

I tried both:

1. I use `TARGET_NAME`. I set `OTHER_CFLAGS` to contain `-DTARGET_NAME=${TARGET_NAME}` in the project setting. And then in the code:

```
NSString *returnStr = nil;
#if TARGET_NAME == PhotoAPI
    returnStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\'%@\');",EventFunStr,dataStr];
#elif TARGET_NAME == LogicTest
    returnStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dataStr];
#endif
return returnStr;
```

However it seems `TARGET_NAME == PhotoAPI` is always true.
 2. I also use `Preprocessor Macros`, and I set `APP` for the App targtet and `UT` for UT. And In the code:

```
NSString *returnStr = nil;
#ifdef APP
    returnStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\'%@\');",EventFunStr,dataStr];
#elsedef UT
    returnStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dataStr];
#else
    returnStr = nil;
#endif
return returnStr;
```

And It always return `nil`.

I use `LLVM GCC 4.2`.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be i the way you define the flags
heres a good doc on using it to call NSLog only in DEBUG

http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/debugging/how-to-create-conditional-log-statements-in-xcode

it said in comments
If you’re going to use GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS instead of OTHER_CFLAGS,
make sure to use the form “DEBUG=1″ instead of “-DDEBUG=1″

Comment: Just notified! I'll check tonight~